# Safari Layout Viewport to match Visual Viewport when Virtual Kbd is open

Tags: safari, viewport, virtual-keyboard, layout-viewport

I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="interactive-widget=resizes-content, ...>` so that the layout viewport resizes to be the same as the visual viewport so that all content is visible and so the layout viewport doesn't scroll vertically when the virtual keyboard is open. This works wonderfully in Chrome on Android, but not on Safari because it is not supported.

I've searched and read high and low and so far can't find a solution to get this behaviour on Safari. Any suggestions? This is for my app cibu.app - see clibu.com for more info.